# How to reduce repetive occurrence of a sequence of elements in XML, without changing .xsd file

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to XML. I use XML to configure my program. The following is the XSD definition of an element used to control the instantiation of one instance.

```
<xs:complexType name="type-A">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="base-type">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name-a" type="xs:token" />
                <xs:element name="name-b" type="xs:token" />
                <xs:element name="name-c" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
                <xs:element name="name-d" type="xs:boolean" />
                <xs:element name="name-e" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
                <xs:element name="name-f" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
                <xs:element name="name-g" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
                <xs:element name="name-h" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

And in the configuration XML file, it looks like following. Here I need to configure 3 instances. In real, I need to instantiate more. Note that, only **name-b** and **name-c** are different between instances.

**Question: Is there anything I can do to remove this repetitiveness?**

```
<type-Xs>
    <instance-1 xsi:type="type-X">
        <name-a>eth0</name-a>
        <name-b>10.0.0.1</name-b>
        <name-c>10001</name-c>
        <name-d>true</name-d>
        <name-e>2048</name-e>
        <name-f>32</name-f>
        <name-g>64</name-g>
    </instance-1>
    <instance-2 xsi:type="type-X">
        <name-a>eth0</name-a>
        <name-b>10.0.0.2</name-b>
        <name-c>11001</name-c>
        <name-d>true</name-d>
        <name-e>2048</name-e>
        <name-f>32</name-f> 
        <name-g>64</name-g> 
    </instance-2>
    <instance-3 xsi:type="type-X">
        <name-a>eth0</ethname>
        <name-b>10.0.0.3</name-b>
        <name-c>12001</name-c>
        <name-d>true</name-d>
        <name-e>2048</name-e>
        <name-f>32</name-f> 
        <name-g>64</name-g> 
    </instance-3>
</type-Xs>
```

Comment: If this is the file you need and that requirement cannot be changed, then no.  You could, however, generate that document automatically from a less repetitive file using a simple XSLT style sheet or some other scripting language of your choice.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thank you a lot. If I got the permission to change that .xsd file. How do you suggest I made change? I have edited the question.

Comment: You could define a single instance with default values and then for every other instance only specify those that are different from that default.  Of course, you'll also need to adapt whatever logic is processing those documents in order to understand the new format.

Comment: @5gon12eder I am considering <xi:include>. But this uses an external file. Do you know a way of not using an external file. Like in programming, just define a variable to be the repetitive part and  `include` that variable later. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've posted an answer with what I've meant.  Why would you need an external file here?  Or did I misunderstand something about your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You could alter the document format to allow specifying a default value for the various names.  The resulting document could look like this.

```
<type-Xs>
    <!-- These shall be interpreted as defaults for all instances. -->
    <name-a>eth0</name-a>
    <name-d>true</name-d>
    <name-e>2048</name-e>
    <name-f>32</name-f>
    <name-g>64</name-g>
    <!-- End of default values. -->
    <instance-1 xsi:type="type-X">
        <name-b>10.0.0.1</name-b>
        <name-c>10001</name-c>
    </instance-1>
    <instance-2 xsi:type="type-X">
        <name-b>10.0.0.2</name-b>
        <name-c>11001</name-c>
    </instance-2>
    <instance-3 xsi:type="type-X">
        <name-b>10.0.0.3</name-b>
        <name-c>12001</name-c>
    </instance-3>
</type-Xs>
```

This approach extends nicely to situations where you suddenly find that an instance does need to alter other fields than `name-b` and `name-c`.  Likewise, you can also provide defaults for `name-b` and `name-c` should this be useful.

Of course, this won't magically change any application processing such a document to understand the new semantics.  You'll either need to go and change those applications as well or provide a small XSLT style sheet that converts the new documents back into the bloated old format.